# creating a restful web service in groovy which returns value from a database on GET request

Tags: web-services, rest, grails, groovy

I want to write a simple web service in groovy/grails which will retun some values from a database table when it receives a GET request.
I am relatively new to web services, though have used grails for a few months now,
How do I start, which api is good?
Thanks
Priyank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How far have you got?

You've at least [read the documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html) yeah?

Comment: i read this sample http://blog.arc90.com/2008/06/04/building-restful-web-apps-with-groovy-and-restlet-part-1-up-and-running/ and it looks pretty straightforwrad, for some reasonings I am looking at the documentation right now... so want to know if restlet is good anything better than that